# Systax error when i use inner join in sql server

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

i have error about sql inner join syntax like this

" Error in SELECT clause: expression near '.'.
Missing FROM clause.
Error in SELECT clause: expression near ','.
Unable to parse query text. "

and this is my query

```
SELECT  VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_RowId,  VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_Code,  VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_Desc,   ARC_Alias.ALIAS_Desc VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_Abbrev,  VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_EffDate,   VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_EffDateTo, VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_OrderOnItsOwn,  ARC_BillSub.ARCSG_RowId,  VS_OrderItem.ARCIC_RowId  
FROM VS_OrderItem,  ARC_BillSub  
INNER JOIN  ARC_Alias 
ON VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_RowId = ARC_Alias.ALIAS_ARCIM_DR 
WHERE( VS_OrderItem.ARCSG_Code =  ARC_BillSub.ARCSG_Code)  
GROUP BY  VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_RowId
```

Have i missing something about this query . Thank you so much.

Comment: You have a combination of the ANSI-89 style and ANSI-92 style joins here. Also you should use aliases on your tables.

Comment: You need a comma between `ARC_Alias.ALIAS_Desc` and `VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_Abbrev`.  Also, the stuff @SeanLange mentions are good ideas.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there's simply a comma missing between ARC_Alias.ALIAS_Desc and VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_Abbrev so SQL Server treats VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_Abbrev as an alias where a dot in between is not allowed. If you really want to use VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_Abbrev as an alias name you should place it between brackets: ARC_Alias.ALIAS_Desc [VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_Abbrev]

Comment: i missing , . Oh my god.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing join to table `ARC_BillSub`. Your query should be something like

```
SELECT  VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_RowId,  VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_Code,  VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_Desc,   ARC_Alias.ALIAS_Desc VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_Abbrev,  VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_EffDate,   VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_EffDateTo, VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_OrderOnItsOwn,  ARC_BillSub.ARCSG_RowId,  VS_OrderItem.ARCIC_RowId  
FROM VS_OrderItem INNER JOIN ARC_BillSub  on VS_OrderITem.columnName = ARC_BillSub.columnName
INNER JOIN  ARC_Alias 
ON VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_RowId = ARC_Alias.ALIAS_ARCIM_DR 
WHERE( VS_OrderItem.ARCSG_Code =  ARC_BillSub.ARCSG_Code)  
GROUP BY  VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_RowId
```

Answer (score 0):

you had a missing comma between the ARC_Alias.ALIAS_Desc AND VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_Abbrev columns, and mixed join types

```
SELECT  VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_RowId,  
        VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_Code,  
        VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_Desc,   
        ARC_Alias.ALIAS_Desc ,--this is the one you missed
        VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_Abbrev,  
        VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_EffDate,   
        VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_EffDateTo, 
        VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_OrderOnItsOwn,  
        ARC_BillSub.ARCSG_RowId,  
        VS_OrderItem.ARCIC_RowId  
FROM VS_OrderItem INNER JOIN 
ARC_BillSub  on VS_OrderItem.<some column name> = ARC_BillSub.<some column name>
INNER JOIN  ARC_Alias 
ON VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_RowId = ARC_Alias.ALIAS_ARCIM_DR 
WHERE( VS_OrderItem.ARCSG_Code =  ARC_BillSub.ARCSG_Code)  
GROUP BY  VS_OrderItem.ARCIM_RowId
```

Answer (score 0):

Reformatted to use consistent join types and added the missing comma your query would look something like this. The biggest challenge you have is due to formatting. It is hard to see when you cram all the columns onto a single line.

```
SELECT o.ARCIM_RowId
    ,o.ARCIM_Code
    ,o.ARCIM_Desc
    ,a.ALIAS_Desc 
    ,o.ARCIM_Abbrev
    ,o.ARCIM_EffDate
    ,o.ARCIM_EffDateTo
    ,o.ARCIM_OrderOnItsOwn
    ,b.ARCSG_RowId
    ,o.ARCIC_RowId
FROM VS_OrderItem o
INNER JOIN ARC_BillSub b on o.ARCSG_Code = b.ARCSG_Code
INNER JOIN ARC_Alias a ON o.ARCIM_RowId = a.ALIAS_ARCIM_DR
GROUP BY o.ARCIM_RowId
```